# SPFx Deployment - Failing Gulp package-solution -- ship

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, custom-actions, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

Update: I was aiming for extenal CDN and I uploaded the artifacts successfully after setting "includeClientSideAssets": false. Still even after adding my app in app  Catalog with no error, adding the app on my site I don't see the custom action on the document library.

I even tried using  PnP PowerShell to add to UserCustomActions.
Still no go..

Quick reply will be helpful.

---

I am trying to deploy command set extension (SPFx) into my tenant site.
The extension works perfectly in debug mode.

In order to deploy it I did the below and even after numerous trials don’t see it in the command bar/context menu for my document library.

1. Gulp bundle –ship  it was successful.
2. “Gulp package-solution –ship” fails and gives me error. Please see below screen shot.
3. Regardless of the above warning as it doesn’t seem valid since I am hosting artifacts from my office cdn, I deployed the sppkg file into App Catalog for my tenant.
4. I created a new site and added the deployed app, still I don’t see my custom action.
   [image]

PS: I was able to deploy app customizer extension exactly the same way. and face this issue only with ListView Command-Set Extension.
Also I have enabled Office 365 CDN and hosted the artifacts for the extension there along with uploading the sppkg into App catalog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused with different deployment options. There are different ways to store your client-side assets (.js files, images, etc.):

1. From app catalogue urls
2. Office 365 CDN
3. External CDN

**From app catalogue urls**

If you haven't activated office 365 CDN feature, then it will be the default location for your files. In that case in `package-solution.json` you should have `"includeClientSideAssets": true` telling SPFx that you want to include your assets inside package and host in SharePoint

*How to upload your assets?* - They are uploaded automatically when you add your app into an app catalogue.

**Office 365 CDN**

If you have activated Office 365 CDN feature, then your assets will go to a special folder at Office 365 CDN. There are two prerequisites: you have `"includeClientSideAssets": true` in your  `package-solution.json` and your `cdnBasePath` in `write-manifests.json` is exactly `"cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->"` - you shouldn't change anything here.

*How to upload your assets?* - They are uploaded automatically when you add your app into an app catalogue.

**External CDN**

If you want to host at external CDN (or at the specific path of Office 365 CDN as in your example) you should modify `cdnBasePath` to point to root folder with your client-side assets. In that case, you also should change `"includeClientSideAssets": false`

*How to upload your assets?* - **On your own. That's the key point here.** As soon as you modified `cdnBasePath` you should take care of static assets deployment. That's the exact reason why it doesn't work for you because you haven't deployed your files to CDN. After bundle and package, you should open `/temp/deploy` and copy all files to your CDN folder.

Also please make sure that `package-solution.json` has features node with your `elements.xml` file, because it actually activates your extension on the site.

Good reading [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn) and [Publish SharePoint Framework client-side web parts to Office 365 public CDN](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/publish-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-office-365-public-cdn/)

Comment: I was aiming for extenal CDN and I uploaded the artifacts successfully after setting "includeClientSideAssets": false. Still even after adding my app in app  Catalog with no error, adding the app on my site I don't see the custom action on the document library.

Comment: Reset your `cdnBasePath` to exactly `"cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->"`, then bundle, package and upload to app catalogue. Go to your site, remove the previously installed app (remove from recycle bin and second stage recycle bin as well). Install the app again and see if it works.

Comment: @DevDen - do you have code for feature activation in your solution? (As I mentioned in my answer # 2)

Comment: @R.Sperre Feature activation gets activated once we add the app to a specific site so no additional code was required for it. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might be missing is the binding of the extension to the target site.

To do that , you can run the below PS script using PnP PowerShell:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline "https://<your-tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<your-site>" -Credentials $credentials

$context = Get-PnPContext
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$context.Load($web)
Execute-PnPQuery

$ca = $web.UserCustomActions.Add()

$ca.ClientSideComponentId = "67fd1d01-84e8-4fbf-85bd-292820ddbf32" // replace it with your value
$ca.ClientSideComponentProperties = ""
$ca.RegistrationId="101"
$ca.RegistrationType="DocumentLibrary"
$ca.Location = "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet"
$ca.Name = "SPFxListViewCommandSet"
$ca.Title = "List View CommandSet"
$ca.Description = "Custom action for SPFxListViewCommandSet"
$ca.Update()

$context.Load($web.UserCustomActions)
Execute-PnPQuery
```

You can find the `ClientSideComponentId` guid value from the `sharepoint > assets > elements.xml` file which you can replace in the above script.

Modified from - [RegionsFooterProvisionCustomizer.ps1](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/12aab3b1b259eee25b479f275d01045452a4b9a4/samples/react-application-regions-footer/RegionsFooterProvisionCustomizer.ps1)

Comment: Are the below steps in addition to adding app on the site ?  I was following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint  and it does no mention of the above step.

Comment: Yes, they need to done post app upload

Comment: I tried running the above powershell cmdlets however I still dont see the custom action :(

Comment: With the recent SPfx, it seems that above code for binding of the extension to the target site is not required. Its already taken care of when the app is added to the individual site. reference : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to correct your config files according to the error message. If you are hosting the assets in your own cdn, *includeClientSideAssets* should be set to false.
2. As Gautam Sheths answer incicates - you also need to provide a way for the feature to be activated on your site. Reference this guide to see an example for when the app is not set to tenant wide deployment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint
   If it is set to tenant wide - you need to use a script to manually activate it (or write it into a site script / provisioning template.)

Comment: Thanks @R.Sperre your point -1 helped me get rid of the gulp package-solution  --ship build failed error.